# Is it ok to publish job openings on my LinkedIn profile to try to earn hiring commissions?

Tags: communication, ethics, advertising, linkedin, switzerland

I receive many contacts from recruiters on LinkedIn.

Some of them genuinely ask if I know somebody who could be interested in the position(s) offered, and they sometimes mention that I could get a commission if I refer somebody who gets hired.

I find asking several contacts personally pretty much time-consuming. I prefer to advertise the position on my feed and request to send a dm if interested (or get to the recruiter directly ?).

Is it something wise/ethical/socially accepted also considering my local market (Switzerland)?

I am employed (not in HR and/or recruitment) and have other projects outside work (publicly displayed on my profile and approved by my employer).

What concerns me in specific is:

- Whether this may impact my employment/employer (not operating in the recruitment / head hunting branch).
- Whether this could be seen in a wrong way from other recruiters in my contacts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, the answer is 'no', it's certainly not *inappropriate* to advertise potential vacancies on your linkedin page, but you need to understand that at that point you're basically moonlighting as a stunted recruiter, passing suitable candidates along to other recruiters who claim  that they'll pay you a small finder's-fee for helping them to place a candidate.

Given how low the rate-of-return will be (your best candidate will be up against many other candidates), the potential to get screwed over by the recruiter deciding not to pay you (which happens often), the potential for reputational damage when your contacts realise that you're acting as a recruitment consultant on the sly and the **strong probability that your company won't take kindly to you touting yourself as a headhunter for their direct competitors**, I'd suggest that you don't do it. It's simply not worth the hassle.